# Selecting lines between two marker patterns

Tags: tcl

How can I select lines which are occurring between two different marker patterns in a file using Tcl?

For example: Suppose the file contains:

```
abc
def1
ghi1
jkl1
mno
abc
def2
ghi2
jkl2
mno
pqr
stu
```

And the starting pattern is `abc` and ending pattern is `mno`. So, I need the output as:

```
def1
ghi1
jkl1
def2
ghi2
jkl2
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a little state machine:

```
      set inrange false
      while {[gets $fh line] != -1} {
          if {$inrange} {
              if {$line eq "mno"} {
                  set inrange false
              } else {
                  puts $line
              }
          } else {
              if {$line eq "abc"} {
                  set inrange true
              }
          }
      }
```